# The input data is not a complete block for CFB mode AES-128 encryption C#

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, aes

I am trying to encrypt data using AES-128, CFB mode. Below code block works for `dotnet 5.x` target framework but gives

> The input data is not a complete block

error at `bw.write()` for `dotnet 4.7.2`. Ideally it should work as CFB mode turns a block cipher into a stream cipher which doesn't need padding. I have also tried `csEncrypt.Write(dataToBeEncrypted, 0, dataToBeEncrypted.Length)` instead of `bw.Write()`. In this case it fails in next line where it converts memory stream to array with same error.

```
     using (AesCryptoServiceProvider Aes128 = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
     {

        Aes128.BlockSize = 128;
        Aes128.KeySize = 128;

        //
        // Specify CFB8 mode
        //
        Aes128.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
        Aes128.FeedbackSize = 8;
        Aes128.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
        //
        // Generate and save random key and IV.
        //
        Aes128.GenerateIV();
        Aes128.Key = key;

        Aes128.IV.CopyTo(savedIV, 0);
        using (var encryptor = Aes128.CreateEncryptor())
        using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
        using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(csEncrypt, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
           bw.Write(dataToBeEncrypted);
           bw.Close();

           cipherBytes = msEncrypt.ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: SSL TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 are obsolete.  You must use an encryption mode that is supported by TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security?force_isolation=true

Comment: The server with which this client interacts supports CFB Mode so the requirement is to encrypt using the same.

Comment: CFB in .NET is problematic. With BouncyCastle you avoid these problems, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69415404/9014097), _BouncyCastle_ section. For CFB8 pass `8` as 2nd parameter in the `CfbBlockCipher` ctor.

Comment: Are you sure? The encryption mode has to meet the RFC requirements,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by removing Aes128.Padding = PaddingMode.None; and letting it get padded by PKC7. Also as answered by @Topaco [How to turn python AES function into C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69413288/how-to-turn-python-aes-function-into-c-sharp-code/69415404#69415404) I trimmed the cipher text to plaintext length to remove padding post encryption.

Updated code :

```
     using (AesCryptoServiceProvider Aes128 = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
     {

        Aes128.BlockSize = 128;
        Aes128.KeySize = 128;

        //
        // Specify CFB8 mode
        //
        Aes128.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
        Aes128.FeedbackSize = 8;
        //
        // Generate and save random key and IV.
        //
        Aes128.GenerateIV();
        Aes128.Key = key;

        Aes128.IV.CopyTo(savedIV, 0);
        using (var encryptor = Aes128.CreateEncryptor())
        using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
        using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(csEncrypt, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
           Console.WriteLine("About to binary write.");
           bw.Write(dataToBeEncrypted);
           bw.Close();
           Console.WriteLine("binary write successful.");

           cipherBytesWithPadding = msEncrypt.ToArray();
        }
        Buffer.BlockCopy(cipherBytesWithPadding, 0, cipherBytes, 0, dataToBeEncrypted.Length);
```