# I have openssl encryption in php and want to produce same encrypted value in C#, .NET

Tags: c#, php, openssl, aes

PHP code:

```
<?php
$value = "My_Plain_Text_Data";
$key = md5("ANONYMOUS_OPENSSL_KEY",true);
$encryptedData = openssl_encrypt($value, 'AES-256-CFB', $key);
?>
```

I tried AesManaged class in C# but could not get same encrypted value. Also in legacy php code(above) there is no IV passed in openssl funtion but the AesManaged requires IV. So it even possible to do it in C# with AesManaged?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var md5Object = MD5.Create();
        var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ANONYMOUS_OPENSSL_KEY");
        key = md5Object.ComputeHash(key);
        var iv = new byte[16]; //kept it empty as we didn't used same in php
        AesManaged aes = new AesManaged
        {
            Key = key,
            Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros,
            IV = iv
        };
        Console.WriteLine($"Key: {BitConverter.ToString(key).Replace("-", "")}");
        byte[] encryptedData = Encrypt(aes, "My_Plain_Text_Data");
        string hexValue = BitConverter.ToString(encryptedData).Replace("-", "");
        Console.WriteLine($"Encrypted data: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encryptedData)}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Encrypted Hex data: {hexValue}");
        var decryptedData = Decrypt(aes, encryptedData);
        Console.WriteLine($"Decrypted data: {decryptedData}");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    private static byte[] Encrypt(AesManaged aes, string plainText)
    {
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
        using MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        using CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(cs))
        {
            sw.Write(plainText);
        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
    static string Decrypt(AesManaged aes, byte[] cipherText)
    {
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
        using MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(cipherText);
        using CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        using StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(cs);
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

Comment: The default padding mode is different in php and c#.

Comment: The PHP code uses CFB with a segment size of 128 bits. This is only supported as of .NET 5, and even then only under the constraint that the plaintext size must be an integer multiple of the segment size (which is more of a bug, since CFB is a stream cipher mode). Which .NET version do you use?

Comment: Another possible bug is the key size (16 byte MD5 output size vs. 32 byte AES-256 key size). PHP implicitly pads the key with 0x00 values, just as it uses a zero IV when none is specified. .NET does not do this. Post your C# code so that a comparison can be made.

Comment: @Topaco added C# code also currently i am using .net core 3.1.

Comment: The C# code you posted uses the default mode CBC, where the PHP code appies CFB. So the modes are incompatible. Under .NET Core 3.1 CFB is not supported, i.e. you cannot port the PHP code (at least not without considerable effort). However, C#/BouncyCastle is an alternative as CFB is supported, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69415404/9014097). Also note that the PHP code extends the too short key with 0x00 values to 32 bytes and that a UTF8 encoding corrupts the ciphertext (hex or base64 encoding is OK).